# How to display HTML Content using window.showModalDialog()

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Will I be able to display a HTML content (not a file) in a pop up window using JS?

I am trying to open a pop up window and display an user defined HTML inside this. I am trying the below, but it doesn't work.

```
window.showModalDialog("<p>Pop up window text</p>","resizable: yes");
```

Can some one suggest me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to `window.open()`, the first (URL) argument of [`showModalDialog()`](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/) is required. Thus, you can't pass it an HTML string. You can either use `window.open`:

```
var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "resizable=yes");
newWindow.document.write('<p>Pop up window text</p>');
```

Or alternatively, use one the existing modal plugins, such as [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or [Twitter Bootstrap Modals](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals). They allow you to easily display a modal window based on the content of an existing HTML element, e.g.:

```
<div id="dialog">
  <p>Pop up window text</p>
</div>

$('#dialog').modal(); // Twitter Bootstrap
$("#dialog").dialog({ resizable: true }); // jQuery UI
```