# How can we display HTML Content through window.showModalDialog()?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that use showModelessDialog () to open pop up window. The modal dialog is open but appears in blank and not render the content.  However, I have some text in the ‘modeless.html’. Below is my code. Can someone suggest ?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
           function OpenModeless() {
               if (window.showModelessDialog) {        // Internet Explorer
                   showModelessDialog("modeless.html", window, "dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:600px; ");
               }
               else {
                   window.open("modeless.html", "", "width=800, height=600, alwaysRaised=yes");
               }
           }
    </script>
```

```html
<img alt="Buddha" class="gallary" src="Images/Gallary/BuddhaThumbs.jpg" onclick="OpenModeless();" />
```

Comment: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

[How to display HTML Content using window.showModalDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036329/how-to-display-html-content-using-window-showmodaldialog)

Try that, the question seems to of been asked previously.
I simply googled "showModalDialog display html content".
Hope this helps.

Comment: When you find a case where a question has already been asked and answered usefully before, the appropriate action would be to flag this question and mark it as a duplicate of the older answered one.