# open response html in new tab browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this code...

```
const handleMonitoring = async (noPKK) => {
  let body = {
  "MonitoringForm[nomor_pkk]": noPKK,
};

const config = {
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

axios.get( 'https://monitoring-inaportnet.dephub.go.id' , body, 
       config)
.then( response => {
    console.log(response.data, "Monitoring");
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
 });
}
```

and for response I get, like this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I0rk.png)

how I can open this "response" HTML in new tab browser...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open a new window with your own HTML, You can use the `window.open` method

```
const handleMonitoring = async (noPKK) => {
  let body = {
  "MonitoringForm[nomor_pkk]": noPKK,
};

const config = {
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

axios.get( 'https://monitoring-inaportnet.dephub.go.id' , body, 
       config)
.then( response => {
    let responseHtml = response.data;
    console.log(responseHtml, "Monitoring");
   //open the new window and write your HTML to it
    var myWindow = window.open("", "response", "resizable=yes");
    myWindow.document.write(responseHtml);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
 });
}
```

Link to the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036329/how-to-display-html-content-using-window-showmodaldialog)

Comment: In addition to this, is there a reason that you need to perform the GET request in the first place? `window.open("https://monitoring-inaportnet.dephub.go.id")` will achieve the same result since the URL doesn't appear to be an API in the first place. It's just a hosted web page

Comment: Maybe there's a reason for the op to do this? since it'll have the URL in the browser window, I am not sure: /, Also he's passing a body to the request and configuration, might alter the response.